# Calculate label's height automatically according to the line of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, masonry

So far I have been working on the calculation of custom cell height. I need to resize the cell automatically after fetching the data.

`self.countLabel` and `self.descriptionLabel` take only one line of text, on the other hand, `self.detailLabel` may contains several lines. So the below codes is how I set up the constraints.

[image]

**CustomCell.m**

```
- (void)initView
{
    self.countLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.countLabel.text = @"AAAAAA";
    self.countLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithPixel:22];
    self.countLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.countLabel];

    self.detailLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.detailLabel.text = @"Number of people: ";
    self.detailLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithPixel:22];
    self.detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor qu_grayColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.detailLabel];

    self.descriptionLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
    self.descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithPixel:26];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.descriptionLabel];

    [self.countLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(20);
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(5);
        make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-10);
    }];

    [self.detailLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(20);
        make.top.equalTo(self.countLabel.mas_bottom);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.descriptionLabel.mas_top);
        make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-10);
    }];

    [self.descriptionLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(10);
        make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-10);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-15);

    }];
}
```

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 9+, this can be easily done using stackviews. You would need to add the labels in a vertical stack view. Position the stackview in the cell using autolayout.

Comment: @TheAppMentor Oop, this application needs to support down to iOS7.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.detailLabel.text = @"Number of peoples: ";
self.detailLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithPixel:22];
...
[self setLabelHeight:self.detailLabel];


- (void)setLabelHeight:(UILabel *)label {
    CGFloat fixedWidth = label.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    label.frame = newFrame;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //if indexPath.row == detailsLabelRow
    //return self.detailLabel.height
    //else 
    //return 1 line height
}
```

Comment: @Wongzigii after fetching the data and setting the text for labels, If you call `[self.tableView reloadData]`, this does not work?

Comment: also make `label.numberOfLines = 0;`

Comment: @Wongzigii make an `IBOutlet` with the detailLabel height constraints and change e.g. `self.hightConstraints.constant = 50; `

Answer (score 0):

you have to set number of lines to Zero first for having multiple lines in `UILabel`.

```
self.countLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

then after setting the the text call bellow method.

```
[self.countLabel sizeToFit];
```

or you can create category class and add below method in that class.

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    [super setText:text];
    [self sizeToFit];
}
```

it will be helpful if you don't need to call it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

use attributed string

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//Calculating height on base of length of text
    UIFont *font =  [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:YOURSTRING //[NSString string withformat:@"\n Yourstring"] \n for: number of lines require for static label in cell
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: font
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;

    //  NSString *height = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", ceilf(size.height)+22];
    return (ceilf(size.height)+22)*0.6; //change 0.6 to 0.9 according to the difference in required and extra calculted height, it works for me every time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for making **dynamic height of label in cell**. And setting its frames according to other label's and its text.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Define Your Cell Here

    //Setting Properties of Labels Here Like this
    cell.countLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
    cell.countLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    cell.detailLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
    cell.detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];

    //Setting label's Text Here
    cell.countLabel.text = @"AAAAAA";
    cell.detailLabel.text = @"Number of people: ";
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLM";

    //Setting Label's Dynamic Height Using setlableFrame Method
    cell.countLabel = [self setlableFrame:cell.countLabel fontSize:22];
    cell.detailLabel = [self setlableFrame:cell.detailLabel fontSize:22];
    cell.descriptionLabel = [self setlableFrame:cell.descriptionLabel fontSize:26];

    //Setting Label's Frame According to Above Label
    cell.detailLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.detailLabel.frame.origin.x,       cell.countLabel.frame.size.height + cell.countLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.detailLabel.frame.size.width, cell.detailLabel.frame.size.height);

    cell.descriptionLabel.frame =  CGRectMake (cell.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.detailLabel.frame.size.height + cell.detailLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.descriptionLabel.frame.size.width, cell.descriptionLabel.frame.size.height);

      return cell;
}
```

Now, Use following method for **dynamic height of cell**.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CGFloat myCellHeight = 0;//For Cell Height

     //For countLabel
     UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     myLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 290, 21.0);//here set frame same as countLabel label's frame. make sure that, You must have setting width same as that label, otherwise you don't have accuracy for this.
     myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
     myLabel.text = @"AAAAAA";
     myLabel = [self setlableFrame:myLabel fontSize:22.0];

     //Adding Height of countLabel
     myCellHeight = myLabel.frame.size.height;

     //For detailLabel
     myLabel.text = @"Number of people: ";
     myLabel = [self setlableFrame:myLabel fontSize:22.0];

     //Adding Height of detailLabel
     myCellHeight = myCellHeight + myLabel.frame.size.height;

     //For descriptionLabel
     myLabel.text = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
     myLabel = [self setlableFrame:myLabel fontSize:26.0];

     //Adding Height of detailLabel
     myCellHeight = myCellHeight + myLabel.frame.size.height;

     return myCellHeight;
}
```

This Method is Used for making **dynamic height** of label according to text.

```
//for setting the dynamic height of labels
-(UILabel *)setlableFrame:(UILabel*)myLabel fontSize:(float)size
{
    CGSize possibleSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: size] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect newFrame = myLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = possibleSize.height;
    //If you want dynamic width of label, then uncomment following line
    //newFrame.size.width = possibleSize.width;
    myLabel.frame = newFrame;
    return myLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of these to dynamic height. Just set constraints of all labels by giving height greater than equals to minimum height of a label and other alignment constraints with vertical alignment in between them. Also don't forget to set **0** to **Lines** property and **Fixed Font Size** for **Autoshrink** property. Now when you are assigning a long text to label, just call

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

and the labels will increase their height according to the text inside.